# nslookup NXDOMAIN error in local network

Tags: networking, network-manager, localhost, hostname

Whenever I nslookup an address inside local network I get NXDOMAIN error. It works on my other computer. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can set DNS server to my router's address. `nslookup ip ip_of_router`